# Vertical alignment of text in a table cell

Tags: alignment, vertical-alignment, xsl-fo

I would like to align the text to bottom in the second cell.
The first cell extends to 2 lines, because of insufficent width and that's OK
But the text in the second cell is only one line and shows up at the top of the cell.
How can I align it to bottom?

I tried vertical-align="bottom" text-align="bottom" text-align="end" on 
row , cell and block levels.. Any of them worked?!?

```
<fo:table font="normal 10 pt Arial, sans-serif" width="100%">
<fo:table-column column-width="40mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="130mm"/>
<fo:table-body>
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
     <fo:block font-weight="bold">Pricing Rate in % p.a. / "Pensionssatz in % p.a.":</fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt">
    <fo:block> 
     **This text I want to be aligned to bottom (in the second line)** 
     </fo:block> 
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`display-align="after"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#display-align) on the table cell:

```
<fo:table-cell padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt" display-align="after">
 <fo:block>
  **This text I want to be aligned to bottom (in the second line)**
 </fo:block> 
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Just as a tip for people who want to align text vertically in the middle of a <fo:block/> - it doesn't work with Apache FOP: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-vertical-align

Comment: If needs to align text vertically in the middle, use the below...

`<fo:table-cell display-align="center">`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone found this issue:

If you have an image and text above you don't want to align after but before:

```
<fo:table-cell display-align="before">
<!-- Your image & text separated in blocks -->
<fo:table-cell>
```