# How to align text vertically in a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like the text to appear inline in my table cell.
However, the text is coming in the single line whatever be the length of text.
I used text_align and padding too, but it did not help.

CSS:

```
table td { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code please?

Comment: It seems your question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874635/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-cell

Comment: table td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

Comment: thanks for that morgano, itried that too but i didnt get

Comment: `table td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; 
}`

Comment: Wait, is that a HTML Table or a java JTable ? The java-Tag has me confused

Comment: maybe think about word wrap? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: In table if your text is of multiple words, then it will break automatically to multiple lines. But if it is of one word only, then it will not break to multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for all of you

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can place your line inside  `ScrollBox` and then place that `ScrollBox` inside the `<td>ScrollBox goes here with content</td>`.

`ScrollBox` will provide you the functionality to wrap as well as Scroll,if required.

You can search google for `Creating a ScrollBox`