# Vertical align the content of 2 columns made in css

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="wrapmytable">   
<div id="custom_left_col">
<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="custom_right_col">
<h5>item1</h5>
<h5>item2</h5>
<h5>item3</h5>
</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#wrapmytable {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#custom_left_col {
float:left;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
#custom_right_col {
float:right;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
background-color: cyan;
}
```

and I would like vertically center the text based of the height of image. As you can see in my Fiddle, the right column do not take the same height. I tried to play with height and many others combination without success. Any clue ?

http://jsfiddle.net/2qXmE/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of text in a table cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874635/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times.  See the links on the right, under `related`?  Check them out.

Comment: I don't know the code which compose the post you mention. At my side I use <div> and not <fo:table>. Tried to apply the tag mentioned without success http://jsfiddle.net/T2p5q/